# Rendering template strings in RiotJS

Tags: riot.js

I have a template string `"<a onclick={ parent.foo }>Link</a>"`. I want pass it to other tag and than render it correctly.
I added short example of my code. It doesn't work, just try to show what I need.

```
<child-tag>
    <div>{ opts.data }</div>
</child-tag>

<parent-tag>
    <child-tag data={ html }></child-tag>

    <script>
    this.html = "<a onclick={ parent.foo }>Link</a>";

    foo() {
      console.log("Hello");
    }
    </script>
</parent-tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

Riot will escape the html where you have `{ opts.data }`. You *can* use the `<raw>` tag as described in the riot documentation. But it may be best to rewrite the code as such.

https://jsfiddle.net/nnyc688e/1/

```
<child-tag>
    <yield/>
</child-tag>

<parent-tag>
    <child-tag> <a onclick={ parent.foo }>Link</a> </child-tag>

    foo() {
      console.log("Hello");
    }
</parent-tag>
```

That's easier to understand too.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! I'm also using `<raw>` tag in my code and I tried to _feed_ it my string, but it renders it as html. But as you can see it contains riot template in it. I also used `riot.util.tmpl()` but my `parent.foo` is not working as expected that way - [Screenshot](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/fc133ae97a1007eb35db2809354f5f35.png)